# Need to replace custom tag to HTML tag using RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace this string

```
Nalsar University of Law
*[span]*, Unitary State University*[*span]*, 
*[span$a1+b2+c3]*Hyderabad, Telangana*[*span]*
```

with this

```
Nalsar University of Law
<span>, Unitary State University</span>, 
<span class="a1 b2 c3">Hyderabad, Telangana</span>
```

using RegEx/PHP, Below is the requirement replacement:-

```
*[span]* => <span>
*[span$a1+b2+c3]* => <span class="a1 b2 c3">
*[*span]* => </span>
```

please help,
I tried this code but failed

```
<?php
$string = 'Nalsar University of Law*[span]*, Unitary State University*[*span]*, *[span$a1+b2+c3]*Hyderabad, Telangana*[*span]*';
$pattern = '/(\*\[)?(\*)?(span)?(([$])([^\s]+))?(\]\*)/i';
$replacement = '<$2$3 class="$6">';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);?>
```

Comment: Use multiple replacements or `preg_replace_callback()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need multiple replacement rules, ordered in proper manner.

For e.g.,

- `*[*` should be replaced with `</`
- `*[` should be replaced with `<` (now you can see ordering is important else `*[* might match`*[`also resulting in unexpected output`)
- `*]` should be replaced with `>`
- `$` should be replaced with `class="`
  and so on,

Here is the code having all rules to take care of all your conversions,

```
$string = 'Nalsar University of Law*[span]*, Unitary State $500 abc $ 20 University*[*span]*, *[span$a1+b2+c3]*Hyderabad, Telangana*[*span]*';
echo preg_replace(['/\$(?!\s*\d)(\w+)(?=\])/i', '/\*\[\*/i', '/\*\[/i',  '/(?<=\$|\+)(\w+)\+/i', '/(?<= )(\w+)(?=\])/i', '/\$(?!\s*\d)/i','/\]\*/i'], [' class="$1"', '</','<', '$1 ' , '$1"',' class="','>' ], $string);
```

Which outputs,

```
Nalsar University of Law<span>, Unitary State $500 abc $ 20 University</span>, <span class="a1 b2 c3">Hyderabad, Telangana</span>
```

Some conversion rules are bit tricky, so let me know if you need explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your response, its working fine, but suppose if string have some amount like $500, here your pattern also replace $500 to class="500

Comment: @Webjosh: That can be easily taken care by putting a negative look ahead after `$` to check replace `$` only if it is not followed by digit or optionally some spaces then digits. I am updating my answer for taking care of your `$500` or `$  20` case. Also, if you have any such more requirement, please update the post so I can take care all.

Answer (score 0):

I have lightweight generic string parser class that can put your string into an array of tag & text elements so you can later easily loop your string adding opening and closing html tags to your string. The reason I say its generic because it can handle any type of tags, you just pass the parser your (your string, a valid tags array, the start of your tag '*[', the end of your tag ']*', the character that tells the parser it has found a closing tag '*', and the option character that signifies the tag has a option '$'). It can also remove uneven tags or fix them, and it can also remove all bogus tags (all invalid tags). Anyway, if you want it, just tell me and I will post it later tonight when I get my notebook from the office which has that class file on it.

Happy New Year!

Comment: Hi Stephanie, Thanks for reply, Please share your code, this can help me.

Comment: Sorry, I was late with this, I actually forgot about it, anyway, here it is... see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class genericParser
{
    /**
    *
    *  @examples... variable value reference
    *
    *  (1), parse a [bbcode] type style tag set
    *
    *  [tag], [tag=option], [/tag]
    *
    *  (0='[')(1='/')tag(2='=')option(3=']')
    *
    *  0 = $sofTag = '['; // start of tag signifier
    *
    *  1 = $iseTag = '/'; // is end tag signifier
    *
    *  2 = $sopTag = '='; // tag has option signifier
    *
    *  3 = $eofTag = ']'; // end of tag signifier
    *
    *  (2), parse a +[generic]+ type style tag set
    *
    *  +[tag]+, +[tag$option]+, +[+tag]+
    *
    *  (0='+[')(1='+')tag(2='$')option(3=']+')
    *
    *  0 = $sofTag = '+['; // start of tag signifier
    *
    *  1 = $iseTag = '+'; // is end tag signifier
    *
    *  2 = $sopTag = '$'; // tag has option signifier
    *
    *  3 = $eofTag = ']+'; // end of tag signifier
    *
    **/


    /**
    *
    *  @name ( sofTag )
    *
    *  @value ( str, character(s) representing... )
    *
    *  the tag sets, start of tag signifier
    *
    *  @access ( protected )
    *
    **/

    protected $sofTag = '*[';


    /**
    *
    *  @name ( iseTag )
    *
    *  @value ( str, character representing... )
    *
    *  the tag sets, is ( end ) tag signifier
    *
    *  @access ( protected )
    *
    **/

    protected $iseTag = '*';


    /**
    *
    *  @name ( sopTag )
    *
    *  @value ( str, character representing... )
    *
    *  the tag sets, option signifier
    *
    *  @access ( protected )
    *
    **/

    protected $sopTag = '$';


    /**
    *
    *  @name ( eofTag )
    *
    *  @value ( str, character(s) representing... )
    *
    *  the tag sets, end of tag signifier
    *
    *  @access ( protected )
    *
    **/

    protected $eofTag = ']*';


    /*
    *
    *  @name ( unknownTags )
    *
    *  @value ( bool, TRUE || FALSE )
    *
    *  TRUE  = remove unknown tags 
    *
    *  FALSE = leave unknown tags in place
    *
    *  @access ( protected )
    *
    */

    protected $unknownTags = TRUE;


    /*
    *
    *  @name ( tidyString )
    *
    *  @value ( bool, TRUE || FALSE )
    *
    *  TRUE  = clean up the string
    *
    *  FALSE = don't clean up the string
    *
    *  @access ( protected )
    *
    */

    protected $tidyString = TRUE;


    /*
    *
    *  @name ( unevenTags )
    *
    *  @value ( bool, TRUE || FALSE )
    *
    *  TRUE  = remove all uneven tags
    *
    *  FALSE = leave all uneven tags in place
    *
    *  @access ( protected )
    *
    */

    protected $unevenTags = TRUE;


    /*
    *
    *  @name ( emptyTags )
    *
    *  @value ( bool, TRUE || FALSE )
    *
    *  TRUE  = remove all empty tags
    *
    *  FALSE = leave all empty tags in place
    *
    *  @access ( protected )
    *
    */

    protected $emptyTags = TRUE;


    /*
    *
    * @name ( maxLines )
    *
    * @value ( int, an integer value, from [1-9] )
    *
    * @equals, the maximum allowed repeated empty line(s)
    *
    * @access ( protected )
    *
    */

    protected $maxLines = 2;


    /*
    *
    * @name ( maxSpaces )
    *
    * @value ( int, an integer value, from [1-9] )
    *
    * @equals, the maximum allowed repeated whitespaces(s)
    *
    * @access ( protected )
    *
    */

    protected $maxSpaces = 1;


    /* class constructor */

    public function __construct ()
    {

    }


    /*
    *
    *  (s) get & set tidyString option(s)
    *
    */

    public function get_maxLines ( )
    {
        return $this->maxLines;
    }


    public function get_maxSpaces ( )
    {
        return $this->maxSpaces;
    }


    public function set_maxLines ( $maxLines = 'default' )
    {
        $t_maxLines = ( int ) $maxLines;

        if ( $t_maxLines >= 1 && 9 <= $t_maxLines )
        {
            $this->maxLines = $t_maxLines;

            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }


    public function set_maxSpaces ( $maxSpaces = 'default' )
    {
        $t_maxSpaces = ( int ) $maxSpaces;

        if ( $t_maxSpaces >= 1 && 9 <= $t_maxSpaces )
        {
            $this->maxSpaces = $t_maxSpaces;

            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    /*
    *
    *  (e) get & set tidyString option(s)
    *
    */


    protected function cleanString ( $strValue )
    {
        return preg_replace ( '/(\R{' . $this->maxLines . '}|\h{' . $this->maxSpaces . '})+/', '$1', trim ( str_replace ( ' ', ' ', $strValue ) ) );
    }


    public function newParser ( $sv, $ta, $return = 0 )
    {
        $sgtl = strlen ( $this->sofTag );

        $egtl = strlen ( $this->eofTag );

        if ( $this->tidyString === TRUE )
        {
            $sv = $this->cleanString ( $sv );
        }

        $lp = 0;

        $hc = 0;

        $rs = array ();

        $co = array ();

        $oc = array ();

        $sl = strlen ( $sv );

        while ( $lp < $sl )
        {
            switch ( $hc )
            {
                case 0:

                $hc = 1;

                $sp = strpos ( $sv, $this->sofTag, $lp );

                if ( $sp === FALSE )
                {
                    $pd = array ( 'sp' => $lp, 'ep' => $sl );
                }
                elseif ( $sp != $lp )
                {
                    $pd = array ( 'sp' => $lp, 'ep' => $sp );
                }
                else
                {
                    $lp = ( $sp + $sgtl );

                    if ( $lp >= $sl )
                    {
                        $lp = $sp;

                        $pd = array ( 'sp' => $sp, 'ep' => $sl );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $hc = 2;
                    }
                }

                break;

                case 1:

                $hc = 0;

                if ( end ( $rs )['tt'] == 'text' )
                {
                    $rs[( key ( $rs ) )]['rs'] .= substr ( $sv, $pd['sp'], ( $pd['ep'] - $pd['sp'] ) );
                }
                else
                {
                    $rs[] = array ( 'tt' => 'text', 'hv' => '', 'rs' => substr ( $sv, $pd['sp'], ( $pd['ep'] - $pd['sp'] ) ) );

                    end ( $rs );
                }

                $rs[( key ( $rs ) )]['hv'] = trim ( $rs[( key ( $rs ) )]['rs'] ) == '' ? FALSE : TRUE;

                $lp = $pd['ep'];

                break;

                case 2:

                $ep = strpos ( $sv, $this->eofTag, $lp );

                if ( $ep === FALSE )
                {
                    $hc = 1;

                    $pd = array ( 'sp' => ( $lp - $sgtl ), 'ep' => $sl );
                }
                else
                {
                    $ct = ( $sv{$lp} == $this->iseTag );

                    if ( $ct === TRUE )
                    {
                        $lp += 1;

                        $cv = strtolower ( substr ( $sv, $lp, ( $ep - $lp ) ) );

                        if ( isset ( $ta[$cv] ) )
                        {
                            if ( ! empty ( $oc[$cv] ) )
                            {
                                $vs = $oc[$cv][0];

                                end ( $rs );

                                $ve = key ( $rs );

                                $rs[$vs]['ee'] = ( $ve + 1 );

                                array_shift ( $oc[$cv] );
                            }
                            elseif ( isset ( $co[$cv] ) === TRUE )
                            {
                                $vs = -1;

                                array_unshift ( $co[$cv], ( end ( $rs ) === FALSE ? 0 : ( key ( $rs ) + 1 ) ) );
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $vs = -1;

                                $co[$cv][] = ( end ( $rs ) === FALSE ? 0 : ( key ( $rs ) + 1 ) );
                            }

                            $rs[] = array ( 'tt' => 'tag', 'tv' => $ta[$cv]['rv'], 'se' => $vs, 'rs' => $ta[$cv]['ct'], 'ct' => TRUE );

                            $hc = 0;

                            $lp = ( $ep + $egtl );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if ( $this->unknownTags === TRUE )
                            {
                                $hc = 0;

                                $lp = ( $ep + $egtl );
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $pd = array ( 'sp' => ( ( $lp - $sgtl ) - 1 ), 'ep' => ( $ep + $egtl ) );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $op = strpos ( $sv, $this->sopTag, $lp );

                        if ( $op === FALSE || $op > $ep )
                        {
                            $cv = strtolower ( substr ( $sv, $lp, ( $ep - $lp ) ) );

                            if ( isset ( $ta[$cv] ) )
                            {
                                ( isset ( $oc[$cv] ) === TRUE ? array_unshift ( $oc[$cv], ( end ( $rs ) === FALSE ? 0 : ( key ( $rs ) + 1 ) ) ) : $oc[$cv][] = ( end ( $rs ) === FALSE ? 0 : ( key ( $rs ) + 1 ) ) );

                                $vs = -1;

                                if ( $ta[$cv]['ov'] == 2 )
                                {
                                    $rs[] = array ( 'tt' => 'tag', 'tv' => $ta[$cv]['rv'], 'ov' => $ta[$cv]['dv'], 'ee' => $vs, 'rs' => $this->$ta[$cv]['wo'] ( $ta[$cv]['dv'] ), 'ct' => FALSE );
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $rs[] = array ( 'tt' => 'tag', 'tv' => $ta[$cv]['rv'], 'ee' => $vs, 'rs' => $ta[$cv]['ot'], 'ct' => FALSE );
                                }

                                $hc = 0;

                                $lp = ( $ep + $egtl );
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if ( $this->unknownTags === TRUE )
                                {
                                    $hc = 0;

                                    $lp = ( $ep + $egtl );
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $pd = array ( 'sp' => ( $lp - $sgtl ), 'ep' => ( $ep + $egtl ) );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $cv = strtolower ( substr ( $sv, $lp, ( $op - $lp ) ) );

                            if ( isset ( $ta[$cv] ) )
                            {
                                $oi = '';

                                $ps = $op + 1;

                                $et = $this->eofTag;

                                if ( $sv{$ps} == '"' || $sv{$ps} == "'" )
                                {
                                    $oi = $sv{$ps};

                                    $et = $sv{$ps} . $this->eofTag;

                                    $ps += 1;
                                }

                                if ( ( $pe = strpos ( $sv, $et, $ps ) ) === FALSE )
                                {
                                    if ( $this->unknownTags === TRUE )
                                    {
                                        $hc = 0;

                                        $lp = ( $ep + $egtl );
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $pd = array ( 'sp' => ( $lp - $sgtl ), 'ep' => ( $ep + $egtl ) );
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $ov = substr ( $sv, $ps, ( $pe - $ps ) );

                                    ( isset ( $oc[$cv] ) === TRUE ? array_unshift ( $oc[$cv], ( end ( $rs ) === FALSE ? 0 : ( key ( $rs ) + 1 ) ) ) : $oc[$cv][] = ( end ( $rs ) === FALSE ? 0 : ( key ( $rs ) + 1 ) ) );

                                    $vs = -1;

                                    if ( $ta[$cv]['ov'] > 0 )
                                    {
                                        $rs[] = array ( 'tt' => 'tag', 'tv' => $ta[$cv]['rv'], 'ov' => $ov, 'oi' => $oi, 'ee' => $vs, 'rs' => $this->$ta[$cv]['wo'] ( $ov ),  'ct' => FALSE );
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $rs[] = array ( 'tt' => 'tag', 'tv' => $ta[$cv]['rv'], 'ee' => $vs, 'rs' => $ta[$cv]['ot'], 'ct' => FALSE );
                                    }

                                    $hc = 0;

                                    $lp = ( $pe + strlen ( $et ) );
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if ( $this->unknownTags === TRUE )
                                {
                                    $hc = 0;

                                    $lp = ( $ep + $egtl );
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $pd = array ( 'sp' => ( $lp - $sgtl ), 'ep' => ( $ep + $egtl ) );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        if ( $this->unevenTags === TRUE )
        {
            $rs = $this->removeUnevens ( $rs, $co, $oc );
        }

        /* parse it back into a string */

        $out = '';

        foreach ( $rs AS $ts )
        {
            $out .= $ts['rs'];
        }

        return $out;
    }


    protected function removeUnevens ( $rs, $co, $oc )
    {
        /**
        *  these are in fix tag formart,
        *  one of those things i will be
        *  adding to this down the road,
        *  so lets change them to remove
        *  tag format, so we avoid doing
        *  2 loops and more sorting than
        *  what really needs to be done.
        **/

        $co = $this->fix_tag_format ( $co );

        $oc = $this->fix_tag_format ( $oc );

        $na = $co + $oc;

        /**
        *  only if we have (a) uneven tag(s)
        **/

        if ( ! empty ( $na ) )
        {
            krsort ( $na );

            foreach ( $na AS $name => $value )
            {
                $total = count ( $rs ) - 1;

                $track = 1;

                $start = $name;

                $stack = array ( $name );

                if ( $name != 0 && $name != $total )
                {
                    /**
                    *  we need to merge  any text type
                    *  array elements that come before
                    *  and after  the uneven tags that
                    *  we are about to unset..
                    **/

                    if ( $rs[( $name - 1 )]['tt'] == 'text' && $rs[( $name + 1 )]['tt'] == 'text' )
                    {
                        $rs[( $name - 1 )]['hv'] = TRUE;

                        $rs[( $name - 1 )]['rs'] .= $rs[( $name + 1 )]['rs'];

                        $track += 1;

                        $start -= 1;

                        $stack[] = $name + 1;
                    }
                }

                /**
                *  for before unset.. we need to
                *  reset all our opening tag 'ee'
                *  position data  so the opening
                *  tag will still point to where
                *  its closing tag  was moved to
                *  after we do this unset..
                **/

                for ( $i = 0; $i < $start; $i += 1 )
                {
                    if ( isset ( $rs[$i]['ee'] ) && $rs[$i]['ee'] > $start )
                    {
                        $rs[$i]['ee'] -= $track;
                    }
                }

                /**
                *  for after unset.. we  need to
                *  reset all our opening tag 'ee'
                *  and closing tag 'se' position
                *  data so both  the opening and
                *  closing tags that exist after 
                *  the unset will still point to
                *  where one another is located.
                **/

                for ( $i = $total; $i > ( $start + $track ); $i -= 1 )
                {
                    if ( isset ( $rs[$i]['ee'] ) && $rs[$i]['ee'] != -1 )
                    {
                        $rs[$i]['ee'] -= $track;
                    }
                    elseif ( isset ( $rs[$i]['se'] ) && $rs[$i]['se'] != -1 )
                    {
                        $rs[$i]['se'] -= $track;
                    }
                }

                /**
                *  now we do the actual unset
                **/

                for ( $i = 0; $i < count ( $stack ); $i += 1 )
                {
                    unset ( $rs[$stack[$i]] );
                }

                /**
                *  reset the array
                **/

                $rs = array_values ( $rs );
            }
        }

        return $rs;
    }


    protected function fix_tag_format ( $o )
    {
        $n = array ();

        $o = array_filter ( $o );

        $k = array_keys ( $o );

        foreach ( $k AS $v )
        {
            $n = $n + array_fill_keys ( array_keys ( array_flip ( $o[$v] ) ), $v );
        }

        krsort ( $n );

        return $n;
    }

    protected function spanParser ( $option )
    {
        return "<span style='" . $option . "'>";
    }
}

/* the valid tags array */

$tags = array ( );

$tags['span'] = array ( 
            'name' => 'Span Tag', /* common name of this tag */
            'type' => 'child', /* the type of tag it is */
            'ov'   => 1, /* should it have an option, 0 = never, 1 = might have, 2 = must always */
            'rv'   => 'span', /* the real tag name */
            'dv'   => 'a1+b2+c3', /* if 'ov' = 2, and no option is found, this deault value is used */
            'ot'   => '<span>', /* when the opening tag has no option, use this */
            'ct'   => '</span>', /* the closing tag */
            'wo'   => 'spanParser' /* when it has an option, call this method to process it */
            );

/* the string to process */

$string = 'Nalsar *[*span]*University *[*span]**[span]*of *[span]*Law
*[span]*, Unitary State University*[*span]*, 
*[span$a1+b2+c3]*Hyderabad, Telangana*[*span]*
';

/* load the parser */

$parser = new genericParser ( );

/* process the string, then print it */

echo $parser->newParser ( $string, $tags );


?>
```